# C# tabcontrol font error when I set the Alignment to left

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, tabcontrol

I have a problem with the font of the `TabControl`.
I set the `Alignment` to `Left`, and use following code to set the font:

```
private void tabControl1_DrawItem(Object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            Brush _textBrush;

            // Get the item from the collection.
            TabPage _tabPage = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];

            // Get the real bounds for the tab rectangle.
            Rectangle _tabBounds = tabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index);

            if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected) {
                // Draw a different background color, and don't paint a focus rectangle.
                _textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
                g.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightSkyBlue, e.Bounds);
            }
            else {
                _textBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
                e.DrawBackground();
            }

            // Use our own font.
            Font _tabFont = new Font("Calibri", (float)11.0, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            // Draw string. Left the text.
            StringFormat _stringFlags = new StringFormat();
            _stringFlags.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
            _stringFlags.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            g.DrawString(_tabPage.Text, _tabFont, _textBrush, _tabBounds, new StringFormat(_stringFlags));

        }
```

I set the font to "Calibri", (float)11.0, but the text in the tabcontrol are smaller. Please refer to the following:

[Font Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l7ct.jpg)
What should I do to set the correct font?

Really appreciate your help!

Eric

Comment: You asked for 11 pixels for some reason, that's what you got.  Error is located between the chair and the keyboard?